# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-endpoints

I am migrating from endpoint V1 to endpoint V2. After updating web.xml file as required and trying to run my application, I am getting the following message:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet

I understand this is probably because the JAR containing this class is not in my class path, but I just updated my App engine SDK with version 1.9.60. Am I missing some others jars? If yes how can I get them?

I am not using MAVEN nor GRADLE.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Eclipse(Oxygen) and I had this same issue earlier today and every answer I found (even in Google's migration guide) only addressed this as if you were using MAVEN or GRADLE. And just being told to "update your dependencies" wasn't helpful either, so here:

What you need to do is download the "endpoints-framework" jar, add it to your "lib" folder in "WEB-INF" folder, and then add the jar file to the Build Path.

I downloaded "endpoints-framework-2.0.7.jar" from [here](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.google.endpoints/endpoints-framework/2.0.7/source-code) (there's a newer version, but I'm just going through exactly what worked for me).

Hopefully this helps the next person who has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your dependencies as well, removing `appengine-endpoints` and replacing it with `com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework`. See [the migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/migrating).

Comment: I eventuallly ended up by updating Eclipse version (up to Oxygen), installing App Engine thru gcloud,  migrating to Google Tools for Eclispe and moving my code into this new environment. It works.. Anyway thank you for your help.