# com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet could not be resolved

Tags: java, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoint

I was using a code from my teacher when I found this error. I tried to search in google how to solve it, just with this page: [java lang classnotfoundexception .com.google.api.server.spi.endpointservlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036019/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-api-server-spi-endpointsservlet/52673313). I just applied what the answers said but the problem didn't solve. What I should do to solve this error?

```
com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet could not be resolved    web.xml /cuentavocales/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF  line 8  Unresolved Servlet Class
```

Comment: You need to provide more details to get help here. E.g. what does web.xml look like, how do you build the project, how are dependencies specified? It is irrelevant that the code is from your teacher, but it is more relevant what do you want to achieve with it? (No, "make it run" is not what we need to hear ;-) , but  what should the code do?)

Comment: Well... Someone in another server say me that I need is to cut this line (<servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>), save, paste this line at the same site and then save again. This solve my problem but if you want to know how is my code I will do in the next comment...

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>vocales.com.Endpoint_vocales</param-value>
Continue next...

Comment: </init-param>
  </servlet>
    <!-- Route API method requests to the backend. -->
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

Comment: please update your question with that XML stuff, chances are higher that other users will stop reading after the question ;) And: if you found a solution, please also answer your own question - so others with a similar problem have a better chance to get help from your learnings.